# Ordinal Date Format in Google Scripts (th, rd, st, nd)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, date-formatting, ordinal

I looked everywhere on here for a simple function to convert a date (in my case, given by a Google Form), into the ordinal format used in contracts:

i.e. 25th day of May, 2018

There was one person who asked the question and someone else labeled it as a duplicate then referred to another answer that didn't answer his question at all! So for those of you who need this - here's a simple function:

```
function ordinal(date) {
  var d = date.getDate();
  var month = new Array ();
  month[0] = "January";
  month[1] = "February";
  month[2] = "March";
  month[3] = "April";
  month[4] = "May";
  month[5] = "June";
  month[6] = "July";
  month[7] = "August";
  month[8] = "September";
  month[9] = "October";
  month[10] = "November";
  month[11] = "December";

  var m = month[date.getMonth()];
  var y = date.getYear();
  return d + (d > 0 ? ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][(d > 3 && d < 21) || d % 10 > 3 ? 0 : d % 10] : '') + " day of " + m +", " + y;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Often times developers' new to a platform end up reinventing the wheel; implementing logic already provided (talking from experience). There is no out-of-box solution for adding those suffixes (st, nd, rd, th), however, in your case you could have leveraged the [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) method to make things a little easier:

```
function getOrdinal(date) {
    var d = date.getDate(),
        suffix = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][(d > 3 && d < 21) || d % 10 > 3 ? 0 : d % 10];

    return Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "d'" + suffix + " day of' MMMM, yyyy");
}
```

A bit of advice, always begin your search with canonical sources. It takes a while but if you intend to leverage Google Apps Script (or any language for that matter) on a regular basis then its best to familiarize yourself with the official documentation and references.

[Here's a link to the official Apps Script Reference Documentation.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/)

Comment: How to actually set up that utilities method was not clear in the documentation. Don't love the patronizing tone of your response, but thanks for giving the format. I'm sure it will come in handy for someone else who's looking.

Comment: I disagree, but that's fine.